# What is the extent of the Galactic Magnetic Field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, galaxies

What is the extent of the `Galactic Magnetic Field`?  What does the `Galactic Magnetic Field` look like from afar (such as half-way between the `Milky Way Galaxy` and `Andromeda Galaxy`)?  Does the `Galactic Magnetic Field` interact with other galaxies's magnetic field?

Also, is there an `Inter-Galactic Wind` interacting with all of the above (in similar nature to how the `Solar Magnetic Field` interacts with the `Galactic Wind`)?

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice [review article on just this subject on the Arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5663).

We're not supposed to post link-only answers, but I'm not sure how much is to be gained from me just repeating what's in the paper. The general message is that we expect magnetic fields to be ubiquitous because moving charged particles are ubiquitous. We don't know the details of what the Milky Way's magnetic field looks like, mostly because it's hard to see the Milky Way in detail from the inside.

The paper does include measurements of the magnetic fields of other galaxies, made by measuring their effect on the polarisation of light, and presumably our magnetic field looks much the same.