# Galactic Birkeland currents

Tags: electromagnetism, cosmology, electric-current, galaxies

Does Milky Way or any other galaxy produce [Birkeland currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkeland_current) such as seen on Earth in auroras? If yes, how strong would they be?

According to [this questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113954/what-is-the-extent-of-the-galactic-magnetic-field) answer, galaxies do have magnetic fields. If there are any radiation exciting intergalactic medium, it could maybe produce similar effects.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdYrgJrBFr0) where they compare it with a rotating pipe.
And [a paper](http://www.ptep-online.com/2018/PP-53-01.PDF) they are referring to.

But do they really exist? What could we observe, if they did or did not exist?

I imagine there should be some light coming from a roughly cone shaped structure at either side of a galaxy that would be produced due to intergalactic medium interacting with the galactic magnetic field. Also if this light was an emission spectrum, we could predict the composition of the intergalactic medium.

But do we observe anything like that?